# Change Hash without updating history stack

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

**Is it possible to alter the hash of a page without calling the hashchange event?**

As in my app I want to do something like:

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){

    hash = ...; // here I change the hash to something else

    window.location.hash = hash; // then update it

});
```

The obvious problem with the code above is that it will cause a loop as window.location.hash will call the hashchange event and then so and so on.

However in my app I only change the hash on a condition:

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){

    var hash = window.location.hash;

    var lastChar = hash.substr(-1);

    if(lastChar != '/') {

        // Add trailing slash
        hash = hash.replace(/\/?$/, '/');                   

        // Update the hash
        window.location.hash = hash;

    }

});
```

So that it only gets called IF a trailing slash isn't found, and then once it's added it then it won't enter the conditional again so it won't do the loop issue mentioned above.

**BUT it will still call the hashchange event!** And two problems arise from this:

1. The History is broken as the previous page is the current page and the browser gets stuck in an infinite stack of the current page.
2. I do an AJAX request in my app on hashchange so it will do the call twice just to add the trailing slash.

Is it possible to add that slash to the hash without it calling the event?

Perhaps doing `window.unbind('hashchange')`. Would that work? And also needs to work in HTML4 browsers so the HTML5 History API isn't an option here.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML5 browsers you can use `window.history.replaceState()` to update the hash without causing a new history entry to be created.

According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), neither `.pushState()` or `.replaceState()` will trigger a `hashchange` event.

Comment: What could I do for HTML4 browsers? Sorry I know I didn't specify. Thanks.

Comment: pushState would still create a history entry but replaceState would work fine... except for it's HTML5 only :)

Comment: @Cameron for HTML4 browsers you may just need to keep some additional extra state to indicate whether the current `hashchange` event was caused by your own deliberate change to the hash, and short-cut the AJAX call if so.  It doesn't solve the "extra history entry" problem, but it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this seems to work:

```
// Unbind hashchange
$(window).unbind( 'hashchange');

// Update the hash
window.location.hash = hash;

// Rebind hashchange                            
$(window).bind( 'hashchange');
```

Any thoughts on this? Such as unknown problems I may have etc.